# TransientObjectException when using Cascade.All

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, orm, nhibernate-mapping

In my object graph, a `Person` has a many-to-many relationship with `Address`, and the join table has additional columns.

**Class Structure**

```
class Person
{
    private IList<PersonAddress> _personAddresses = new List<PersonAddress>();

    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<PersonAddress> PersonAddresses 
    { 
        get { return _personAddresses; } 
        set { _personAddresses = value; } 
    }
}

class PersonAddress 
{
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(...) {...}
    public override int GetHashCode(...) {...}
}

class Address 
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
}
```

**Mapping**

```
class PersonMapping : ClassMapping<Person>
{
    public PersonMapping()
    {
        Id(x => x.ID, m => m.Generator(Generators.Identity));

        Bag(
            x => x.PersonAddresses, 
            m => {
                m.Cascade(Cascade.All);
                m.Access(Accessor.Field);
            },
            r => r.OneToMany()
        );
    }
}

public class PersonAddressMapping : ClassMapping<PersonAddress>
{
    public PersonAddressMapping()
    {
        ComposedId(map =>
        {
            map.ManyToOne(
                x => x.Person, 
                m => {
                    m.Cascade(Cascade.All);
                }
            );

            map.ManyToOne(
                x => x.Address,
                m => {
                    m.Cascade(Cascade.All);
                }
            );

            map.Property(x => x.Description);               
        });
    }
}

public class AddressMapping : ClassMapping<Address>
{
    public AddressMapping()
    {
        Id(x => x.ID, m => m.Generator(Generators.Identity));   
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
using (var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
{
    var person = new Person();
    var address = new Address();

    var personAddress = new PersonAddress 
    {
        Address = address,
        Person = person,
        Description = "This is my home address"
    };

    person.PersonAddresses.Add(personAddress);  

    session.Save(person);

    // exception of NHibernate.TransientObjectException
    transaction.Commit(); 
}
```

**Exception**

```
object references an unsaved transient instance - 
save the transient instance before flushing or set 
cascade action for the property to something that 
would make it autosave. 

Type: MyApp.Models.Address, Entity: MyApp.Models.Address
```

I believe that my above code should not be problematic, as I'm saving a `Person`, which cascades down to the `PersonAddress`, which then cascades down to the `Address`.  However, NHibernate is telling me to either autosave it (with cascade?), or to save it myself.

**Workaround**

```
session.Save(person);
session.Save(address);

transaction.Commit();
```

However, this is very problematic as the actual production code is much more complex than the short example.  In the actual production code, I have an `Organization` object which contains a list of `Person` (which then has personaddresses, and addresses).

Is there a way to solve this problem without having to hack in an additional `Save` call, as it's difficult to write that in a generic way while try to separate my application logic from the persistence logic.

**Why the workaround wont work for my scenario**

```
// where unitOfWork is a wrapper for the session
using (var unitOfWork = unitOfWorkFactory.Create()) 
{
    var organization = unitOfWork.OrganizationRepository.GetById(24151);

    organization.AddPerson(new Person {
        PersonAddress = new PersonAddress {
            Address = new Address(),
            Description = "Some description"
        }
    });

    unitOfWork.Commit();
}
```

As you can see, the `UnitOfWork`, `UnitOfWorkFactory`, and `OrganizationRepository` are all abstractions, and therefore would be impossible for me to save both address and person without leaking that implementation detail, which I think I should be able to do if the persistence cascaded as I expected.

My question is, how do I persist `Address` without explicitly telling NHibernate to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your stuff would work ... unless the mapping of the `Person` and `Address` won't be representing the `composite-id`.

Despite fo the fact, that you could use `Cascade.All` inside of the `CompositeId` mapping

```
ComposedId(map =>
{
    map.ManyToOne( x => x.Person, 
            m => { m.Cascade(Cascade.All); // Cascade here is not applied
```

this won't be applied. The [`<composite-id>` *(doc 5.1.5)*](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-compositeid) sub-element `<key-many-to-one>` does not support cascading.

**BUT**, all the stuff would work, if the `PersonAddress` would have some surrogated key, and references to *Person* and *Adress* will be mapped as standard `many-to-one` with `cascade="all"`

Also see answers here [NHibernate - How to map composite-id with parent child reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5486569/1679310) ... to get more reasons to use surrogated, not composite id

Comment: Is this possible to accomplish without using a surrogate key?

Comment: No. I am sure :( sorry. You can still call session.Save(address) ... then OK. But in the scenario you prefer... no. Cascade cannot work on composite Primary Key insertion. The Address must exist in this case

Answer (score 1):

One thing is that Address is not a child of PersonAddress.  PersonAddress is the child of both Person and Address.  You can tell because of the ManyToOne.

I would also map the other side of the relationship from Address down to PersonAddress.  You need to this so that you can mark the relationship INVERSE because it looks like you want the child PersonAddress to handle the ownership of the relationship.

Here's a quick mapping that should save everything.

```
public class Person
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; protected set; }
    public virtual String Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PersonAddress> PersonAddresses { get; protected set; }

    public Person()
    {
        PersonAddresses = new List<PersonAddress>();
    }

    public virtual void AddPersonAddress(PersonAddress personAddress)
    {
        if (PersonAddresses.Contains(personAddress))
            return;

        PersonAddresses.Add(personAddress);
        personAddress.Person = this;
    }
}

public class PersonMap : ClassMapping<Person>
{
    public PersonMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id, map =>
        {
            map.Column("Id");
            map.Generator(Generators.GuidComb);
        });

        Property(x => x.Name);

        Bag(x => x.PersonAddresses, map =>
        {
            map.Table("PersonAddress");
            map.Key(k =>
            {
                k.Column(col => col.Name("PersonId"));
            });
            map.Cascade(Cascade.All);
        },
        action => action.OneToMany());
    }
}

public class Address
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; protected set; }
    public virtual String AddressLine1 { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PersonAddress> PersonAddresses { get; protected set; }

    public Address()
    {
        PersonAddresses = new List<PersonAddress>();
    }
}

public class AddressMap : ClassMapping<Address>
{
    public AddressMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id, map =>
        {
            map.Column("Id");
            map.Generator(Generators.GuidComb);
        });

        Property(x => x.AddressLine1);

        Bag(x => x.PersonAddresses, map =>
        {
            map.Inverse(true);
            map.Table("PersonAddress");
            map.Key(k =>
            {
                k.Column(col => col.Name("AddressId"));
            });
            //map.Cascade(Cascade.All);
        },
        action => action.OneToMany());
    }
}

public class PersonAddress
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }

    public virtual String Description { get; set; }
}

public class PersonAddressMap : ClassMapping<PersonAddress>
{
    public PersonAddressMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id, map =>
        {
            map.Column("Id");
            map.Generator(Generators.GuidComb);
        });

        ManyToOne(x => x.Person, map =>
        {
            map.Column("PersonId");
            map.NotNullable(false);
        });

        ManyToOne(x => x.Address, map =>
        {
            map.Column("AddressId");
            map.NotNullable(false);
            map.Cascade(Cascade.All);
        });

        Property(x => x.Description);
    }
}
```

And passing unit test

```
    [Test]
    public void CascadeMapTest()
    {
        using (ISession session = SessionFactory.OpenSession())
        {
            using (ITransaction tx = session.BeginTransaction())
            {
                var person = new Person { Name = "Test" };
                person.AddPersonAddress(new PersonAddress { Address = new Address { AddressLine1 = "123 main street" }, Description = "WORK" });

                session.Save(person);

                tx.Commit();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I get the same exception when I give `Address` a reference to `PersonAddress` and mark inverse to true (and when false for that matter).

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your help, however I cannot use this solution as I don't have the possibility of modifying the `PersonAddress` table, hence the reason for using a composite id.

Comment: yeah.  then look at my mappings and use the info from Radim for the composedId stuff. not really a big change.  the import part is the location of the cascade.all and inverse.